# How to get Excel to find the next Tuesday when the date in a cell is Monday, Friday, Saturday, or Sunday

Tags: excel, date

I'm setting up a spreadsheet to calculate dates based off of one trigger date. If one of the subsequent dates is not a Tuesday, Wednesday, or Thursday, I need Excel to find the date of the next Tuesday. (In my office, certain meetings can only happen Tuesday through Thursday, so if the calculated date falls on a Monday or a Friday, I'd like Excel to give me the next Tuesday.)

I'm trying to use IF and WEEKDAY together, and I'm pretty sure something is wrong with how I wrote the "or" logic. Here's what I have:
=IF(WEEKDAY(D9,1)=NOT(OR(3,4,5)),D9+7-WEEKDAY(D9+7-3),D9)

But the formula returns false every time and gives me the date in the cell itself.

Answer (score 3):

With a date in **A1**, use:

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A1),A1+2,A1+1,A1,A1,A1,A1+4,A1+3)
```

*(almost as easy as a VLOOKUP())*

Answer (score 0):

> =IF(MOD(A1-1,7)>2,A1+2-MOD(A1-1,7)+7,A1+2-MOD(A1-1,7))

A1 is your trigger date